# How can I express the natural logarithm of a power series in terms of another power series?

Tags: logarithms, power-series

Can I express the expression
$$\ln\left( \sum_0^{\infty} a_nx^n\right)$$ in terms of another power series?

Can I differentiate the term $$\ln\left( \sum_0^{\infty} a_nx^n\right)$$ and get $$\frac{\sum_1^{\infty} na_nx^{n-1}}{\sum_0^{\infty} a_nx^n}$$ Then do the term by term power series division and get a new power series $$ \sum_0^{\infty} b_nx^n=\frac{\sum_1^{\infty} na_nx^{n-1}}{ \sum_0^{\infty} a_nx^n}$$ In the end, can I integrate the power series $$ \sum_0^{\infty} b_nx^n$$ to get $$ \sum_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}b_nx^{n+1} + \ln a_0$$ and say it is equal to the original expression $\ln\left( \sum_0^{\infty} a_nx^n\right)$ ?

I saw some one set $\ln\left( \sum_0^{\infty} a_nx^n\right)$  equal to another power series in terms of another power series with coefficents related to $ a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$. But when I try to do what I just shown to confirm what is in the book, the result did not match.

If it is possible to express $\ln\left( \sum_0^{\infty} a_nx^n\right)$  in terms of another power seize,s can you show me the first two terms in the new power series and their relation to $ a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$?

Comment: To get the coefficients $b_n$,  this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Multiplication_and_division) might be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do both and get the same results using for sure the integration constant leading to $b_0=\log(a_0)$.

What is the simplest method ? Probably the long division if you need only few terms.

Using both methods, you should get things like
$$b_0=\log(a_0)$$
$$b_1=\frac{a_1}{a_0}$$
$$b_2=-\frac{a_1^2}{2 a_0^2}+\frac{a_2}{a_0}$$
$$b_3=\frac{a_1^3}{3 a_0^3}-\frac{a_2 a_1}{a_0^2}+\frac{a_3}{a_0}$$
$$b_4=-\frac{a_1^4}{4 a_0^4}+\frac{a_2 a_1^2}{a_0^3}-\frac{a_3
   a_1}{a_0^2}-\frac{a_2^2}{2 a_0^2}+\frac{a_4}{a_0}$$
$$b_5=\frac{a_1^5}{5 a_0^5}-\frac{a_2 a_1^3}{a_0^4}+\frac{a_3
   a_1^2}{a_0^3}+\frac{a_2^2 a_1}{a_0^3}-\frac{a_4 a_1}{a_0^2}-\frac{a_2
   a_3}{a_0^2}+\frac{a_5}{a_0}$$

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full answer, but too long to put in a comment.

You can try

$$ \ln\left(a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n \right) = \ln(a_0) + \ln\left(1 +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n x^n \right) $$

where $a_n = a_0c_n$, then apply the power series for
$$ \ln(1+t) = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-t)^k}{k} = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \dots $$

of course this only converges if the inner series
$$ \left| \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n \right| < a_0 $$

Answer (score 0):

You can express the given power series in terms of products of binomial terms and then add the logarithms of the binomial terms, which are easily constructed.

We first divide out the constant term so that the leading coefficient of the series to $1$, thus:

$\ln\sum\limits_0^\infty a_nx^n=\ln(a_0)+\ln(1+\sum\limits_1^\infty b_nx^n); b_n=a_n/a_0$

We now factor the series on the right using iterative polynomial division:

$1+\sum\limits_1^\infty b_nx^n=(1+b_1'x)(1+b_2'x^2)(1+b_3'x^3)(...);b_1'=b_1$

And then

$\ln\sum\limits_0^\infty a_nx^n=\ln(a_0)+\sum\limits_1^\infty \ln(1+b_n')$

where we plug in the standard Maclaurin series for the binomial logarithms.

We consider an ecample. The Maclaurin series for $1/(1-x)^2$ begins with

$1+2x+3x^2+4x^4+5x^4+6x^5+...$

Clearly the leading coefficient is already $1$ so the constant term in the logarithm series is $0$. Now we carry out the divisions, calculating the quotient series out to the $x^5$ term (matching the input) at each stage:

$1+2x+3x^2+4x^4+5x^4+6x^5+...=(1+2x)(1+3x^2-2x^2+9x^4-12x^5+...)$

$=(1+2x)(1+3x^2)(1-2x^3+9x^4-6x^5+...)$

$=(1+2x)(1+3x^2)(1-2x^3)(1+9x^4)(1-6x^5+...)$

So including terms through $x^5$ in the Maclaurin series of the binomial logarithms we have

$\ln(1+2x+3x^2+4x^4+5x^4+6x^5+...)=(0+)[2x-2x^2+(8/3)x^3-4x^4+(32/5)x^5+...]+[3x^2-(9/2)x^4+...]+[-2x^3+...]+[9x^4+...]+[-6x^5]+...$

Upon combining like terms we obtain

$\ln(1+2x+3x^2+4x^4+5x^4+6x^5+...)=2x+x^2+(2/3)x^3+(1/2)x^4+(2/5)x^5+...,$

which matches the known result $\ln[1/(1-x)^2]=-2\ln(1-x)$ to the input acvuracy.